$A-B$ semi positive definite can tell us the information of the positive inertia index
Suppose $f,g$ are symmetric real quadratic forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the positive inertia index of $f\geq$the positive inertia index of $g$.
My idea: By using matrix, this question becomes: If $A,B$ are symmetric matrix such that $A\geq B$, then the positive inertia index of $A\geq$the positive inertia index of $B$. Without loss of generality we can suppose $B$ is a diagonal matrix, that is
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
I_{p_2} &  &\\
 & -I_{s_2} &\\
& & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The difficulity is tha $A,B$ can not be diagnoanlised at the same time. I can find an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that
$$
P^{T}AP=\begin{pmatrix}
I_{p_1} &  &\\
 & -I_{s_1} &\\
& & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But how to show $p_1\geq p_2$? I have no idea.

What does the inertia index of a matrix mean?

Hint: if $p_1<p_2$, then $(n-p_1)+p_2>n$.

use $B$'s congruence to a diagonal matrix,  i.e. $A-B\succeq \mathbf 0\implies C^TAC - C^TBC = C^TAC - \begin{pmatrix}
I_{p_2} &  &\
& -I_{s_2} &\
& & 0
\end{pmatrix}\succeq \mathbf 0$  which tells you that $C^TAC$ has a positive definite subspace of dimension at least $p_2$ (check leading principal submatrix of that size) so $A$ does as well.

Thank You, I have worked out this problem by using Courant-Fischer Theorm! Also it can be proved directly by using cantraspositive, if $p_1<p_2$, then $n-p_1+p_2>n$, by using this I can find a nonzero vector lies in two spaces with dimensions $n-p_1$ and $p_2$ with respect, this will lead us to construct two spaces from two different kinds of eigenvectors!

Note that $f - g$ is a positive-definite quadratic form; thus there is a basis such that the corresponding matrices $F, G$ satisfy
$$
  F - G = I
$$
with $I$ the identity. Such $F, G$ have the same eigenvectors, and the eigenvalues $\alpha$ of $F$ and $\beta$ of $G$ satisfy
$$
  \alpha - \beta = 1.
$$
If $\beta > 0$ then $\alpha > 0$, so the positive index of $f$ is $\geq$ that of $g$.

I've realized that this argument only works if $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x \ne 0$. I'll have to work on the general case...
